# How to install phpMyAdmin only with PHP7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.3

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with Apache, PHP7.3, and MariaDB.
Now I need to install phpmyadmin and I tried to do that using the code below:

```
apt install phpmyadmin
```

But this command will install and replace the PHP7.4 with PHP7.3, whereas I need to keep using PHP7.3.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does it replace the PHP version, or switch it? If it switches it simply [switch it back](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/) to PHP 7.4, if it replaces it then you could go ahead and [re-replace](https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/#attachment_26248) the versions?

Comment: I think there is another way to install it. You could download it from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and proceed with the installation instructions

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed PHP 7.4, since Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) includes PHP 7.2 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php)?

You seem to have gone outside of the standard packages (perhaps you're using the excellent effots provided by Ondřej Surý  at https://deb.sury.org/). In this case, it's going to cause you some amount of grief to mix and match the newer PHP with the distribution's phpMyAdmin, because of these dependency problems.

You could force the matter. This is probably going to cause you problems, since Bionic packages phpMyAdmin 4.6.6, which is only supported up to PHP 7.1. https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies has some instructions on ignoring the dependencies. I recommend avoiding this solution.

You could install your own phpMyAdmin. Download the source from phpmyadmin.net and uncompress it to your web root. You may need to add a short configuration file, `config.inc.php`, but mostly it just works with the default settings. https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html has a quick start section.

You could downgrade your PHP, but you've already stated this isn't a good option for you, and I'm not sure how the Ubuntu package managers get phpMyAdmin working with this newer PHP version.

Clearly, I think the best solution for you to is to install your own phpMyAdmin.